# Use of IF function in google spread sheet for arrays

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to understand to use properly the `IF` function in Google Sheets for an array of cells. My problem is the following:

> I want to sum some data in a row, let's say from `D12` to `N14`, but I want to check if any of the cells is empty with the function `ISBLANK` and to show a result if and only if at least one cell in the range is not empty.

Hence I used the formula `=IF(ARRAYFORMULA(ISBLANK(C14:N14));; SUM(C14:N14))`. Unfortunately, the result is not what I expected. For instance, if the second cell is not empty and the first cell is empty it does not perform the sum. It seems that the function `ISBLANK` checks only the first cell.

So the question is: How can I use in a more proper way the above functions?

Answer (score 1):

do this:

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/SUM(C14:N14)),"")
```

[image]

[image: ()`]

Comment: The problem is that I do not want many zeros in the spreed sheet and your solution gives me zero if there is nothing in the array. Maybe I should have been more spefific: I want to sum if and only if there is something to sum and I do not want zero if all the array is empty.

Comment: @Giovanni yes it takes the reciprocal of the reciprocal, which will error if the sum is `0` and then put in an empty string.

Comment: ok, now I got it! Sorry about before, but I did not understand the logic behind your function...

Comment: It would be hard to understand the logic as it was flawed.  Now it should work.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(COUNTA(C12:N14)=0;; SUM(C12:N14)))
```

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

or like this:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(""&SUM(C12:N14); "^0$"; )*1
```

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

Comment: I have a question, where can I found a good guidebook for Google Sheets and its programing languages? I mean: should I learn some visual basic stuff?